# Change URL on select change

Tags: javascript, jquery, form, event-handling, url

I've made a method, which inserts a new query parameter, when the value of a select changes, then reloads the page. I've had enough of URL jQuery hax, so I figured it would be a great idea to put the query parameters in an array, and manipulate it that way. I'm a little unsure whether or not this is the best way of doing it, so some input would be appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<select id="selCurrency">
   <option value="">Choose currency &hellip;</option>
   <option value="DKK">Danske kroner</option>
   <option value="NOK">Norske kroner</option>
   <option value="SEK">Svenske kronor</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$("#selCurrency").change(function(){
     var val = $(this).val(); // This should be the new CurrencyCode, extracted from a select box 
     var pag = window.location.pathname;
     var url = window.location.search;
         url = url.replace("?", "").split("&"); // Clean up the URL, and create an array with each query parameter

     var n = 0;
     for (var count = 0; count < url.length; count++) {
         if (!url[count].indexOf("CurrencyCode")) { // Figure out if if/where the Currency is set in the array, then break out
             n = count;
             break;
         }
     }

     if (n !=0) {
        url.splice(n,1); // If the Currency was set, remove it from the array
     }

     var len = url.length;
     var newUrl = url.join("&"); // Restringify the array

     if (len > 0) { // Check whether or not the currency is the only parameter, then build new URL with ? or &
        newUrl = pag + "?" + newUrl + "&CurrencyCode=" + val;
     } else {
        newUrl = pag + newUrl + "?CurrencyCode=" + val;
     }

     window.location.href = newUrl; // Finished, let's go!
  });
```

You will notice, that I've used the jQuery selector engine, while the rest is native JS. Would it be smarter/faster to use native JS to check for the onchange event?

```
document.getElementById("selCurrency").onchange( /* My function right here, mayn */ );
```

Comment: According to vanilla-js.com, you can run 12,137,211 ops/second of `document.getElementById('test-table');` In comparison, you can run 350,557 ops/second of `$jq('#test-table');`. So there's definitely a performance overhead.

Answer (score 1):

if you already use jQuery for something else in your page, it doesn't bother if you use jQuery or not.

if it's the only JQuery in your page, I suggest to change it to "vanilla" javascript, because you won't need to load the jquery library.

Some may say that often the jquery library is already in the browser cache, but still there's no need to add a library/framework for just one call.

Comment: Oh yeah. Completely agree. In this particular solution, jQuery is already loaded, I was just wondering if there was a difference performance wise.